# How can people with low reputation point review suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I visited the page `http://stackoverflow.com/review` and saw there were details been given for reviewing like 'You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits'.

Then how can many people with low reputation point can review ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can always reject / approve suggested editson your own posts, no matter what your reputation, which counts as "reviewing".

Comment: Like gnat edited my question than how can I review Suggested Edits?

Comment: @LitisqeKumar if there is an edit to your own post that you can review, you will be notified.  However, on Stack Overflow, the queue often moves quickly enough that you don't always get a chance to review before other users have already approved/rejected the edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A poster is alerted to suggested edits on their posts. If they accept or reject the edit, that counts as a review. (It's also a binding vote.)

Comment: And sometimes they accept utter garbage edits, and sometimes reject improvement because they are so tightly-bound to the prose in their perfect original. Historically, someone could have reviewed whilst above 2000 and then have gone below 2000 by offering a bounty, getting caught posting spam, having their socks removed, etc (any other means of losing rep). So, theoretically, even a currently low-rep account could have previously reviewed edits.